# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am testing my insert statement:

```
insert into Gebruiker
values ('Sonja123', 'Sonja', 'Van der Vliet', 'kastanjelaan 45',NULL, '3771jx', 'Heteren', 'Nederland', '1980-04-01','Pdel42@hotmail.com', 'WEBM1MAMV', 1, 'Poekie', 'wel')
```

But every time I try to test it, I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'wel' to data type Bit.

My trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CHECKVERKOPER
   ON  Gebruiker
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @USER_NAME VARCHAR(70)
    SET @USER_NAME = (SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM INSERTED)

    IF (SELECT Verkoper FROM Gebruiker WHERE gebruikersnaam = @USER_NAME) = 'wel'
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Verkoper WHERE Gebruiker = @USER_NAME) = 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Gebruiker SET Verkoper = 'niet' WHERE gebruikersnaam = @USER_NAME    
        END
    END
END
GO
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: SQL Server Triggers 101: The Inserted table can have multiple rows in it? So your trigger is broken from the start.

Comment: So to produce that error column `Verkoper` must be of `bit` datatype. I have just tested that myself and thats exactly what happens. Change `Verkoper` to a string type and it works.

Comment: The Inserted table can have multiple rows in it? YES

Comment: ^^^ but your code only handles 1 row e.g. `SET @USER_NAME = (SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM INSERTED)` because a variable can only contain one value.

Comment: Triggers fire once per _statement_, not _row_. If an `insert` statement adds 42 rows then `inserted` will contain 42 rows. If your trigger absolutely cannot process more than one row then it should check the number of rows and use `throw` (or `RaIsError`) to indicate that there is an unresolved issue.

Answer (score 1):

To get the error you are getting column `Verkoper` must be of type `bit`. Quite how you fix that depends on the overall design, either change the datatype or use the correct column. Thats trivial.

However the reason I am answering the question is because your trigger currently doesn't handle the fact the the `Inserted` pseudo-table can contain multiple rows.

You should always be looking to solve T-SQL problems as set-based problems not procedural problems - because relational databases are optimised for set-based operations.

I think the following `update` statement performs the same function as the code you posted, but if not hopefully you get the idea and can adapt it.

```
UPDATE Gebruiker SET
  Verkoper = 'niet'
WHERE gebruikersnaam in (SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM INSERTED)
and (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Verkoper V WHERE V.Gebruiker = gebruikersnaam) = 0
and Verkoper = 'wel';
```

In fact (thanks David), replacing the words 'niet' and 'wel' with the bit values 0 and 1 might be the solution you are looking for:

```
UPDATE Gebruiker SET
  Verkoper = 0
WHERE gebruikersnaam in (SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM INSERTED)
and (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Verkoper V WHERE V.Gebruiker = gebruikersnaam) = 0
and Verkoper = 1;
```

You would need to change your `insert` statement to also use 0 or 1 for `Verkoper`.

Note: Its best practice to list the column names for your insert. It not only means you can add columns later without breaking your insert, but it makes it obvious to people not familiar with your scheme what column each value is being inserted into.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I am going to tested.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of varchar to bit is not language-aware.  It's baked-in only that 'true' and 'false' can can be converted.

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
>   is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

[bit (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: David do you know the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61549479/1127428)?