# Use the Merge-OUTPUT function to dump results with msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, merge, output

I frequently use the `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` tool in SQL Server for automated reports and such but I've never really used it to for an update/delete type statement in the `@query` section.

Is it possible to do so?  When I run this query, it gives 0 results and doesn't execute the actual Merge and Delete function within the `@query` section.

I'm running a test scenario where I know there should be results, and that it should be deleted but no dice.  Any advice appreciated as I may be missing something as I'm thinking it might be an order issue.  But I thought putting it within the `@query` should execute as should be.  Query style below:

```
DECLARE @results NVARCHAR(1000)

Select @results = N'
MERGE Table1 A
USING Table2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID and A.recorddate = B.recorddate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN delete
OUTPUT
$action,
deleted.*;';

Begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'Test',
    @recipients= 'test@test.com',
    @query = @results,
    @from_address = 'test@test.com', 
    @subject ='Delete Row',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Merge Test',
    @query_result_separator='$',
    @query_result_width =32767,
    @query_result_no_padding=1,   
    @body = 'Results',
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;  
End
```

The result of the query should execute and delete the unneeded row and then output the results which I'm hoping could be exported to the `.CSV` and e-mailed to me so I can review what was deleted.

EDIT:
Got it!  Just going to use a temporary table to store results and dump that into a .csv and drop it at the end

```
select * into #temptable from TableA where 0=1;
MERGE Table1 A
USING Table2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID and A.recorddate = B.recorddate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN delete
OUTPUT
$action,
deleted.* INTO #temptable;
drop table #temptable
```

Comment: So just to clarify, you've managed to get a straightforward select query working as `@query`? Just not a merge?

Comment: While the docs say "any valid SQL", that feels wrong. It wouldn't surprise me if at the lower level it only allows read access not write access. You might find something in a log somewhere because the results are prepared in an extended SP using a DLL. One which might be quite useful as it allows quick formatting of query results!

Comment: Dale - yes, the query works by itself as the merge.  It just doesn't work embedded in that e-mailer.  I believe you are correct, that might be the case as far as read access only.  That's what I'm thinking as of right now!  Well, worst case is I'll rewrite it another way.  I was hoping this way would have worked.

Comment: Sorry my question was, have you managed to pass a simple non-merge, query into `sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: Oh yes I have - I have many reports that send out daily/weekly/monthly, but all of them have just been select based (that I can think of).  I don't think I've ever created one that does an update/delete/insert yet

Comment: I have another idea - is it possible to dump results into a temp table using Merge?  It looks like it might not allow it as I'm testing it.  See above edit example of it

Comment: I can't see how adding a temp table would make any difference. And I doubt its specific to using the merge statement. My guess is you can only read data, not update it. One thing to test would be to have your dynamic SQL call a stored procedure. Start the sp as a straight select, see if that works, then add the merge, see if that works.

Comment: Oh i think i got it! I got the temp table, i needed to initialize it first (duh).  I'm just going to use that temp table result to dump it into .csv and then drop it at the end.  that works for me.  Thanks for helping me run ideas through my head Dale!

Comment: If `sp_send_dbmail` fails for any reason (can't put mail in the queue?), do you have any idea if your statement will be executed? This is a bad idea, you shouldn't tie database operations to external operations. Not if you want those operations to be reliable.